# Linear dependence of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a set of linearly dependent matrices $A^i_j$ for $i,j \in \{1, \ldots, d\}, d\in \mathbb{N}$, is there a way to conclude that the following set(s) of matrices are also linearly dependent:

$$\{A^i_j\otimes A^j_k \}, \{A^i_j\otimes A^j_k\otimes A^k_l\}$$
and so on.

Of course, if these sets contained every tensor product combination of each $A^i_j$ this would be more straightforward, but as can be seen, these sets don't quite contain all combinations.

Comment: Sorry for misreading earlier. It's impossible to reach a conclusion without more information.

Comment: No problem! Appreciate the time you took anyway :-)